# How to programmatically read the line from the source code where exception occurs

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am designing an eclipse plugin which reads the stack trace from console when an exception occurs.

Plugin is basically used for content based searching when an exception happens. The user explicitly selects the keywords from the stack trace but plugin implicitly need the line from the source code causing the exception, so that together the source code line and keywords can be used for better search results. In that case Plugin can't make changes to the source code.

Console gives me the file, package and the line number but I want the corresponding line from the source code which caused the exception.

For example if i have an exception like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

I would want the line 13 from the source code of Test.java

Comment: **`exception` stack trace** provides detail what happen in stack trace unless you have not declared to print it out, why reinventing the wheel?

Comment: The plugin would get triggered when the exception happens. Plugin doesn't have the exception object. Plugin only processes the stack trace from console. Without the exception object how can plugin get the line.

Comment: So are you using something like `org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners`? The existing `JavaExceptionConsoleTracker` knows how to open the source from a exception in the console.

Comment: @greg-449 yes I am using `org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners`. I'll check out `JavaExceptionConsoleTracker`. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You may probably not have the exact reusable code, but this something which you can explore.

In the Throwable class you can access the StackTrace Elements List and get the Line numbers of the code from where it was propogated.

Note:

> At times you may get more than one StackTrace Elements in the
>   exception object, you may to then iterator and get the one you want
>   the line number for.

Something like

```
catch(Throwable e){
             e.getStackTrace()[e.getStackTrace().length - 1].getLineNumber();
         }
```

Comment: But I can't access the modify the source code causing the exception

Comment: You mean you want to modify the source code from plugin

Comment: No, I want the line causing the exception without modifying the source code. Sorry for poor english.

Comment: Are you considering my note as you would need to change the logic , so that's not the case.

Comment: I was explaining that at times you get multiple stack trace in the getStackTrace() method as List. You can get the last element as that is generally the actual root cause like in my updated answer.